# Send alert if Azure ML pipeline fails

Tags: azure, azureportal, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to add an alert if Azure ML pipeline fails. It looks that one of the ways is to create a monitor in the Azure Portal. The problem is that I cannot find a correct signal name (required when setting up condition), which would identify pipeline fail. What signal name should I use? Or is there another way to send an email if Azure pipeline fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What signal name should I use?

You can use `PipelineChangeEvent` category of `AmlPipelineEvent` table to view events when ML pipeline draft or endpoint or module are accessed (read, created, or deleted).

For example, according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/monitor-azure-machine-learning#analyzing-logs), use `AmlComputeJobEvent` to get failed jobs in the last five days:

```
AmlComputeJobEvent
| where TimeGenerated > ago(5d) and EventType == "JobFailed"
| project  TimeGenerated , ClusterId , EventType , ExecutionState , ToolType
```

**Updated answer:**

According to [Laurynas G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/897665/laurynas-g):

```
AmlRunStatusChangedEvent 
| where Status == "Failed" or Status == "Canceled"
```

You can refer to [Monitor Azure Machine Learning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/monitor-azure-machine-learning#analyzing-logs), [Log & view metrics and log files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-log-view-metrics) and [Troubleshooting machine learning pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-debug-pipelines)

Comment: Well, in porta.azure.com I go to Monitor -> Alerts -> Create Alert Rule -> Condition  and I can't find neither PipelineChangeEvent, nor AmlComputeJobEvent

Comment: You need to enable [Send information to Log Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/monitor-azure-machine-learning#collection-and-routing)

Comment: I ended up using the following, but I think it is okay to accept this answer AmlRunStatusChangedEvent | where Status == "Failed" or Status == "Canceled"